# When is it appropriate to consult with the publisher/editor prior to manuscript submission?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, publishability

Motivated by the answer written by @ÉbeIsaac to this question: [Can I write a paper on a method that is novel but yields similar results compared to existing methods?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59389/can-i-write-a-paper-on-a-method-that-is-novel-but-yields-similar-results-compare)

This participant wrote

> Also make sure you go through the Journal guidelines and consult with
>   the publisher/editor prior to manuscript submission.

The part that I would like to understand better is *consult with
the publisher/editor prior to manuscript submission*.

My question:

**When is it appropriate to consult with the publisher/editor prior to manuscript submission?**

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac - I hope you will weigh in here.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on factors such as the field, the reason for contact etc. In my experience it is usually appropriate to consult with the publisher/editor in two cases, when:

(1) you have a short question about something that is not answered in their submission guidelines, or;

(2) you would like to send them an abstract to determine whether they think the potential submission fits with their journal.

---

Comment: Just for clarification, in case (2) what you may want to send is an *extended abstract* (e.g. 1-2 pages) rather than the short 1-paragraph abstract you see at the beginning of an article.

Comment: Both comment and answer are helpful.