# Is improving a simple algorithm without beating the state of the art still publishable?

Tags: computer-science, publishability

In a particular field there are two algorithms being used:

- Algorithm *Simple*: you understand it in five minutes, you can implement it in fifteen.
- Algorithm *State of the Art (SOA)*: requires very specific mathematical knowledge to understand and is hard to code. Beats *Simple* by a big margin, both in terms of speed and results.

However *Simple* is more popular because of its simplicity and not-so-bad results. *Simple* has 130 citations, *SOA* has 80. In 2016 *Simple* had 20 citations, *SOA* 17.

While trying to use the *Simple* paper, our results were so bad we spent more than a week looking for a bug in our implementation. Finally, we discovered a one line change that makes it work much better, improving a mathematical approximation in the *Simple* paper that is easily overlooked. After reviewing recent literature, it seems this is not known (we can reproduce recent papers).

We can prove that the one line change is statistically better and equally fast as *Simple* but statistically worse and slower than *SOA*. We also have a 5-line-change improvement which makes it both better and faster than *Simple*, worse results than *SOA* but slightly (10–20%) faster than *SOA*.

What should we do? Since we are not beating *SOA*'s results and it is a one line change it may be hard to publish, but it is clearly something people in the field would profit from.

*Edit*: some have noted it's similar to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59389/can-i-write-a-paper-on-a-method-that-is-novel-but-yields-similar-results-compare) question. There are two differences:

1. We are not coming up with a different algorithm, just making a small modification.
2. On the other hand we are a simpler algorithm than SOA, and there's value in it. In particular the 1-line change is as simple as the *Simple* algorithm and the 5-line change is still much simpler than the *SOA* algorithm.

Comment: Not having done so myself, but I *hope* that's publishable (i.e., it sounds like people should have that available).

Comment: Related: [Can I write a paper on a method that is novel but yields similar results compared to existing methods?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/59389/7734)

Comment: I can't really add enough for a full answer, but I'd say it's worth publishing... The simple case is used, having a better version would be good AND the way it's improved might be educational for others.

Comment: There are certainly examples in the "standard" numerical algorithms for optimization, where the difference between a "good" and "bad" version of the algorithm is no more than a re-arrangement of the same mathematical equation, to reduce the effect of rounding errors accumulating over several iterations in a rather non-obvious way. Publishing the *reason* why your version is better may be a valuable contribution to the subject, however trivial the change to the code might look.

Comment: A good idea is to establish that it works better than Simple on a representative range of problems. Then, simplicity may be an argument for publication.

Comment: Also, there is the following philosophical argument as to why this should be publishable: suppose that Simple+ImprovementA+ImprovementB beats SOA. If the person who discovers ImprovementA buries it in a drawer instead of publishing it, we will never know until someone randomly rediscovers *both* ImprovementA and ImprovementB at the same time, which is much less lilkely.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that both of your versions are still much simpler to understand and implement than the SOA?

Comment: You spent a week debugging the *SIMPLE* algorithm and you found a 5-line change that makes it work *MUCH BETTER*.  Why are you so confident that your algorithm is correct?

Comment: Well if it matches SOA, then maybe it has some Okham value.

Comment: See [How inefficient can a sort algorithm be?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1077v1) and also [Sorting the Slow Way: An Analysis of Perversely
Awful Randomized Sorting Algorithms](http://www.hermann-gruber.com/pdf/fun07-final.pdf).

Comment: Your claim your new result is faster than the state-of-the-art-for-accuracy.  Well, now there are two state-of-the-art algorithms, the existing one for accuracy and your modified Simple, for speed.

Comment: @Ray yes, the 1-line change is just multiplying some quantity by a magical number, the 5-line change is still much simpler than SOA and easy to understand if you understand the Simple algorithm

Comment: @emory it didn't work well for our application, but the same code was able to reproduce the results on the original paper. The modification gives other results, you can then perform a t-test to show that they are statistically better than the original.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sure this is publishable, but the real question is *where*?

The applied mathematical community, especially the one in which the state of the art methods are developed will probably not see the improvement of the simple algorithm as worth publishing in their venues. Why should they? They know that there is something better which they understand well. In fact, I know of at least one journal which states explicitly that algorithms published there need to beat the state of the art to be suited for them. But the community of practitioners who may be struggling with the nuts and bolts of the state of the art method and often fall back to use the simple method may be impressed.

So, choose you publication venue right and things should go well.

Comment: One problem the referees of the publications the “community of practitioners” read, are likely to be the experts that can understand the state of the art….

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mathematical community, but in other communities a possibility would be that of submitting a _short communication_, or equivalent.

Comment: Computer science is the one area where anything less than an order if magnitude improvement is often considered uninteresting...

Comment: I would check out a "letters" track of a conference (e.g., "Operations Research Letters". Usually these are shorter papers for this type of thing.

Answer (score 25):

Adding to @Dirk's fine answer:

- If you publish **free-license code** rather than just an algorithm/pseudo-code - that's a publishable novelty.
- If your analysis of *Simple* is not merely an application of the analysis used to obtain *SOA*, then this in itself is publishable unless entirely trivial; I would also **look into whether the same 'trick' can be applied in other settings**, which would allow for a paper on "Improving X, Y and Z by frobincating the bar" and the *Simple* imporvement would only be a part of it.
- Simple-to-implement algorithms can sometimes **beat asymptotically-better-but-heavy algorithms under various constraints** of various kinds, such as limited asymptotic space complexity, no randomness, switching from average case to worst case, or even not having enough memory to store the program code, requiring very compact implementations (e.g. in hardware) and no dependence on large libraries. Perhaps you could explore that.

Comment: frobincate (sic.) was a new word to me. In case it is so to others as well, [here's a reference](http://catb.org/esr/jargon/html/F/frobnicate.html).

Answer (score 18):

As a civil engineer who develops mathematical models, I publish this sort of result fairly regularly. In my field, we focus on models that are 'good enough' and can be adopted and adapted quickly easily. Quickly means we can make more profit on future jobs, and easily means less chance of mistakes / easier for reviewers to check the working.

We would tend to take this sort of thing to conferences rather than scientific journals.

Journals tend to need the greatest, newest and best. At conferences (specifically, those I'm familiar with that are attended by civil engineers), people are often interested in what is practical that they can use tomorrow.

So, I'd recommend submitting a paper to a relevant conference describing the usual problem and how you've improved a common method for solving it. The people who use the simple method will be pleased to attend your talk. You won't be lauded as the next Einstein, but your work will still be referencable in the conference proceedings, and you'll be able to put it in your CV.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on the issue of *where* to publish, you should also consider *in what format*.  For example, IEEE has several "Letters" (I seem to recall an "Information Processing Letters") that tend to be short (4-page) papers that could welcome something like what you describe.

Also, some conferences (and journals) welcome also *position* papers that, among other things, can challenge commonly accepted paradigms (what you describe could fit into this --- you're challenging the perception of not-so-good performance of the simple algorithm).

Lastly --- some conferences and journals welcome *short* papers, where there is novelty but not necessarily substantial amounts of new ideas or analysis or experimental results.

Comment: Some journals call them "short communications" as well.